# what is fastest allowable serial baudrate?

Tags: arduino-mega

what is the fastest serial read the Mega can do?
begin.Serial1(1024000) is accepted for compiling, but reading jibberish

any suggestions on a faster device?

Comment: The divisors should give you 1 Mbps even.  However, on that board it is not just the Mega2560 which needs to do this - the 8u2/16u2 USB-serial and its firmware has to manage it as well.  Fortunately, you have similar Atmel parts on both ends of that very short link, so customization should be possible (you could ignore the host request and simply set both dividers to 0).  But your software has to keep up, too.  You may want to look at a different architecture where the application processor itself speaks USB, leonardo-style.

Comment: Why do you need "the fastest serial baudrate"? This is to communicate with what device exactly?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - looks like you are using a different UART than the one proxied to USB.

Comment: device is a FANUC CNC Serial encoder...1024000 baudrate is fixed, but only need to output request strobe, then capture 77 bits serial input into buffer, then ignore while running rest of program to decipher what was read, when done arduino generates clock pulse to send another 77 bit word... I have it triggered via the request strobe falling edge interrupt to read input, but havent figured out how to save this into a buffer (i'm kinda new to this stuff) or if its even possible...

Answer (score 6):

The Arduino Mega 2560 runs at 16 MHz. There are online calculators making this easy, as the calculation is not a straight and simple formula.

http://wormfood.net/avrbaudcalc.php

which shows using 16 MHz

| Baud Rate | UBRR(dec) | UBRR(hex) | % of error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 3332 | 0x0D04 | 0.0 |
| 600 | 1666 | 0x0682 | 0.0 |
| 1200 | 832 | 0x0340 | 0.0 |
| 2400 | 416 | 0x01A0 | 0.0 |
| 4800 | 207 | 0x00CF | 0.2 |
| 9600 | 103 | 0x0067 | 0.2 |
| 14400 | 68 | 0x0044 | 0.6 |
| 19200 | 51 | 0x0033 | 0.2 |
| 28800 | 34 | 0x0022 | 0.8 |
| 38400 | 25 | 0x0019 | 0.2 |
| 57600 | 16 | 0x0010 | 2.1 - Barely OK |
| 76800 | 12 | 0x000C | 0.2 - GOOD |
| 115200 | 8 | 0x0008 | 3.7 - BAD |
| 230400 | 3 | 0x0003 | 7.8 - BAD |
| 250000 | 3 | 0x0003 | 0.0 |

Where it is noticeable that the Mega's Arduino boot loader uses

```
mega.menu.cpu.atmega2560.upload.speed=115200
```

which is above the acceptable 1% error rate.

While it is possible to support different baud rates than stated above, it is not advisable, as the above values are the standard values. Values in between are very atypical and likely not trustworthy on the corresponding other side of the connection.

As I see your above example is 1024000, it is also worth noting that HardwareSerial.cpp implements a method to convert the requested baud rate to configuration of the USART, and I would not necessarily trust it for non-standard baud rates, especially on older version of the Arduino IDE. You may want to try the latest 1.5.8+ and verify the rate.

Comment: This is interesting. Why does the default Arduino bootloader use a baudrate with such a high error rate?

Answer (score 1):

It depends mainly on CPU frequency, see *USART/Baud rate settings* in datasheet. For example at 16MHz it might go up to 2Mbps. But you need also consider error in baudrate which is important if communication with "3rd party" device.

Comment: If you have both MCU under control you can also consider *USART in SPI mode* with sync clock.